# Захват экрана windows на Go с вкл. Scale

Tags: winapi, golang

Использую библиотеку github.com/kbinani/screenshot для создания скриншотов рабочего стола, приложение будет работать в качестве сервиса Windows, и есть проблема следующего характера, если в настройках экрана Windows стоит увеличение интерфейса, то экран захватывается лишь частично, т.е. как я понимаю на запрос GetMonitorInfo мы получаем не реальное разрешение в пикселях а увеличенное, есть ли какие то функции api для проверки масштабирования интерфейса на Win7 и выше. Нашел функцию GetDpiForMonitor , но она только Win 8.1/2012R2 и выше, а хотелось бы иметь поддержку Win7.

Comment: Возможно ваше приложение не не является HighDPI aware, добавьте соответствующий параметр в манифест приложения.

Comment: Как можно добавить HighDPI aware в консольное приложение?

Comment: Также, как и в любое другое, посредством [манифеста приложения](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/SbsCs/application-manifests)

Comment: Поролблвал gdiScaling true/false, но как я и ожидал, это неработает.

Comment: А при чем тут gdiScaling?

Comment: А что тогда нужно сделать?

Comment: Всё получилось, оказалось я немного неправильно манифест использовал. Единственное пока на win7 не тестировал.